# duplicate check for rows in smart-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I have a duplicatecheck function which basically compares the current edited row(newRule) with the other rows in the list(ruleList). It works fine because it displays an error when duplicate coloumns are detected, but it resets if ANYOTHER row has duplicates ( my app allows user to edit the rows). I want to the error to stay and not reset, which is inside the else statement ( duplicate.error=false). In my if and else, how do I make it so that the error=true only for that specific row/index. I defined index as a paramter, so that's basically that specific row.

```
$scope.duplicateCheck = function (newRule, ruleList, duplicate, index) {
        var error = false;

        //the logic goes here, blah blah blah if duplicates detected in all the columns, error is set to true

        if (error) {
            duplicate.error = true;

        } else {
            duplicate.error = false;
            duplicate.item = '';
            duplicate.index = -1;
        }
    };
```

```
$scope.duplicateAppType = {
            error: void(0),
            item: '',
            index: -1
        };
```

Html  (rule= row that is currently being edited also defined in my ng-model, theList=all the rows in the st-table)

```
<td class='errorClass'
<p ng-show="duplicateAppType.error"{{Duplicate here}}<p>
</td>
<select>
   ng-model=rule.names
   ng-change=duplicateCheck(rule, theList, duplicateAppType, $index)
</select>
<br>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure the functionality you're trying to achieve. If you're just setting table row data, you could do an angular.forEach on your API data response and pull out duplicates based on keys there.

Comment: I have many rows and 6 coloumns ( name, id#, color, isEdited,etc) with dropdowns in each coloumn. When values are changed in a row. my duplicate check function compares that row to the other created rows(the ones that the user obviously makes).It works right now for 2 rows. But say I have 3 rows (all coloumns in each row are different). If I edit row 1 to make it exactly the same as row 3, error WILL pop. Now if I edit row 2 and make random changes(that are not similar to row 1&3), my function will return false since there are no duplicates when row 2 was compared to row1 and row 3.

Comment: then it goes to the else and sets duplicate.error to false, and therefore my error in my template goes away.  The previous error should still be there